# Customize action sheet of QLPreviewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uibarbuttonitem, uiactionsheet, qlpreviewcontroller

I want to add another menu item to the action sheet, other than the print item. I have written a custom QLPreviewController. So looking to add email button below to the print button of the action sheet.

please help....

Answer (score 0):

I want to do that as well but I assume that instead of adding to that menu, we'll have to create a new buttom with a new menu with our own items in it instead. The trick will be finding out how those default items (ie print) get generated.